# What is the extra set of () or {} doing to change what gets redirected to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I was doing some testing on bash on my understanding of file descriptor redirection and discovered that:

```bash
((echo STDOUT; echo STDERR >&2;) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-)  2> /dev/null
```

and

```bash
 (echo STDOUT; echo STDERR >&2;) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-   2> /dev/null
```

gave different results.  The first giving the expected output of `STDERR` since the `stdout` and `stderr` fds were swapped, but the second giving an unexpected output of `STDOUT` as if the fds were never swapped in the first place.

Which to me is surprising.  In this context, I don't see what the extra parenetical would be doing to change the output.  Using braces has the same effect.

#### EDIT

So what I thought was "expected" results was actually wrong as I was visualizing incorrectly what was happening.  What is actually happening is (with the left side of the -> being the file descriptor (or in the case of the last column, the command) and the right side being to what the underlying file handle will be output to):

```
1 -> stdout   1 -. ,-> stdout   1 -. ,-> /dev/null   echo STDOUT     -> stderr   
                  X                 X                
2 -> stderr   2 -' '-> stderr   2 -' '-> stderr      echo STDERR >&2 -> /dev/null
```

With @JohnKugelman explanation, this now makes sense.

```
1 -> stdout   1 -> stdout       1 -. ,-> stdout      echo STDOUT     -> /dev/null
                                    X                
2 -> stderr   2 -> /dev/null    2 -' '-> /dev/null   echo STDERR >&2 -> stdout
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirections are processed first, even if they're written after a command. This fact is crucial. It means `2> /dev/null` isn't performed last.

Although `2> /dev/null` is at the end of the line it's actually executed before the subshell starts. `(subshell) 2>/dev/null` is actually `2>/dev/null (subshell)`. That means it executes before the descriptors are swapped in the first example, but afterwards in the second.

Let's take a deep dive.

##### With outer subshell

> ```
> ((echo STDOUT; echo STDERR >&2;) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-)  2> /dev/null
> ```

This is equivalent to:

```
2>/dev/null (3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- (echo STDOUT; >&2 echo STDERR))
```

The steps are:

1. `2> /dev/null`: fd 2 is redirected to `/dev/null`.
2. The outer subshell starts.
3. `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`: fds 1 and 2 are swapped.
4. The inner subshell starts.
5. `echo STDOUT`: Writes to fd 1, which is `/dev/null`.
6. `>&2`: fd 1 is redirected to fd 2, which is the stdout of the original shell.
7. `echo STDERR`: Writes to fd 1, which is stdout.

##### Without outer subshell

> ```
> (echo STDOUT; echo STDERR >&2;) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-   2> /dev/null
> ```

This is equivalent to:

```
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- 2>/dev/null (echo STDOUT; >&2 echo STDERR))
```

The steps are:

1. `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`: fds 1 and 2 are swapped.
2. `2>/dev/null`: fd 2 is redirected to `/dev/null`.
3. The subshell starts.
4. `echo STDOUT`: Writes to fd 1, which is stderr of the original shell.
5. `>&2`: fd 1 is redirected to fd 2, which is `/dev/null`.
6. `echo STDERR`: Writes to fd 1, which is `/dev/null`.

Comment: I think my main problem was that I was not conceptualizing file descriptors properly, though your explanation definitely helped.  Thx for setting me straight.